# Keep WPF window over the taskbar without taking focus

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have a WPF application that I'd like to maintain on top of the taskbar.

The issue is that whenever you interact with the taskbar, the program goes underneath and stays there.

Example:
 [image: Overlay example]

What I've tried:

- `Activate()` Takes control of the keyboard and removes focus from current application, don't want that
- `BringToView()` Did not bring window on top of taskbar
- `Show()` Did not bring window on top of taskbar
- `Activate()` -> `ClearFocus()` would steal focus still

Some properties of the window:

- `WindowStyle="None"`
- `Topmost="True"`

The preferred behavior is that if the taskbar were to go on to, it would then return once the action with the taskbar is complete. It would preferably also not steal focus at any point from the keyboard or any other process.

I've looked across various questions here and MSDN but haven't had anything work yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mean a topmost state like the [on-Screen Keyboard](https://www.howtogeek.com/240288/how-to-use-the-on-screen-keyboard-on-windows-7-8-and-10/)?

Not a chance with default tools. The on-screen Keyboard can pull that off, because it is actually part of the Windowing System. Just like the Taskbar and Start Menu. Just like the different UI elements are part of your Window. But a image you host in it, is only a guest.

It would be one thing if you could intercept and draw on top of the Video Signal. It is possible but a good way away from WPF.

Comment: Just experimented with it, yes exactly like on-screen keyboard would be perfect behavior. Shame it's not possible - is it possible to activate the wpf window without taking focus then? That way I can bring back the window after `x` time?

Comment: @AndrewRaleigh I am not sure. But it seems the Activated event tells you when you (re)aquired focus: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.window.activated | This seems to be th Lifecycle overview for that class: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/app-development/wpf-windows-overview It might hold some usefull information.

Comment: Didn't seem to work the way I like it, I'll try a workaround and update the post if I find anything. Thanks for the help!